# wp_query should show stickies first

Tags: wp-query, sticky-post

I have the problem that my theme is for some reason always showing the latest posts at first. I would however like it to show all stickies at first and then show the regular ones. Here is the code:

```
<!-- Begin top thumbnails --> 
<div class="home-thumbs" style="width:<?php echo $top_width; ?>px;">  

<?php 
$home_query = new   WP_Query("cat=$slider_cat&ignore_sticky_posts=0&showposts=$top_row_posts"); $i = 0;?>
<ul class="thumbs" style="width:<?php echo $top_width; ?>px;">
<?php while ($home_query->have_posts()) : $home_query->the_post();
    $do_not_duplicate = $post->ID; $i++; ?>     
<li class="post-<?php the_ID(); ?> thumb-big">
<dl class="captioned-image"><dt>
<?php get_the_image( array( 'custom_key' => array( 'thumbnail' ), 'default_size' =>   '320x320', 'width' => '320', 'height' => '320' ) );?></dt>
<dd><span><?php echo get_the_title(get_the_ID());?></span></dd>
</dl>
</li>
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); $i = 0; ?>
</ul>
</div>
```

By setting sticky posts to zero I would expect it to show sticky posts at the beginning oif the loop but it seems that the loop counter for some reason descends through the post id's and simply showing the latest posts first, ignoring all my wp_query args.

Comment: `print_r` or `var_dump` `$home_query` to see the the query WordPress is sending to the database, it sounds like you have an error in your query vars so WP is producing a default query and ignoring them.

Answer (score 1):

Well for starters, the query arg [`showposts` has been replaced by `posts_per_page`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters) since WP v2.1

I don't think any of your query args are being ignored (well, maybe save `showposts`; I haven't checked to see if backwards compatibility support still exists for the arg). That said, I do not know what value your `$top_row_posts` variable holds or what it is supposed to represent, but it's entirely possible that the data is being inserted into the query in a format unusable by Wordpress.

But (as Milo has corrected me) you are correct, setting `ignore_sticky_posts` to `0` should ensure that sticky posts are bubbled to the top. [From the codex WP_Query page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Sticky_Post_Parameters),

> ignore_sticky_posts: [...] *Note: ignore/exclude sticky posts being
>   included at the beginning of posts returned, but **the sticky post will
>   still be returned in the natural order of that list of posts returned***.

While I'm not entirely sure what's going wrong with your query, I propose a work-around using two separate queries that would explicitly ensure the desired effect - one for the sticky posts, and a separate for the rest:

The ideal way to implement a dual-query approach would be to modify the main query using [the `pre_get_posts` action](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) in a plugin or your theme's *functions.php* file, and then run your second "sticky" query directly in your theme's home-page/front-page template. Something along the lines of

**functions.php:**

```
function modify_home_query( $query ) {
    /* If not displaying the home/front page or not processing the main query, bail out. */
    if( is_admin() || !$query->is_main_query() || !( is_home() || is_front_page() ) )
        return;

    /* If this is the main query for the home/front page, tell it to ignore sticky posts entirely. */
    $query->set( 'post__not_in', get_option( 'sticky_posts' ) );
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'modify_home_query' );
```

Note that [the WP_Query method `is_main_query()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_main_query) is only available as of WP v3.3.

Above the main loop in **front-page.php** or **home.php** or **index.php** (with conditional encapsulation):

```
$stickyQuery = new WP_Query( array(
        'cat'                    => $slider_cat,    //Select posts from the slider category id
        'ignore_sticky_posts'    => 0,
        'post__in'               => get_option( 'sticky_posts' ),
        'posts_per_page'         => -1             //Get ALL the stickies
    );
while( $stickyQuery->have_posts() ) : $stickyQuery->the_post();

   //... ( Sticky Post Template Here )

endwhile;
wp_reset_query();

//... ( Main template loop here )
```

As Milo has pointed out, regardless of whether you choose to focus on correcting your query or creating a work-around, you may wish to double check the value of your `$slider_cat` variable to make sure it is a valid category ID.

Comment: I think you've got `ignore_sticky_posts` backwards, setting it to *true* will show the posts in natural order. I suppose my point was make sure `$slider_cat` is a valid value, though that shouldn't affect sticky posts, so the comment doesn't entirely make sense in hindsight.

Comment: @Milo I believe you're correct! I admit I became quite confused by the codex's description and various examples of the `ignore_sticky_post` arg. Does that mean that when the arg is set to _true_ `WP_Query()` **will** prioritize any sticky posts returned by the query?

Comment: I've edited my answer to reflect Milo's correction and designate my solution as a work-around.